# Qt Custom Slot QWebView

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qwebview, qwebkit, qpushbutton

I'm fairly new to Qt and I'm trying to work with Signals and Slots and I'm having a bit of trouble creating custom Slots:

```
public slots:
    void resetUrl(){
        this->load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
    }
```

(Then, in my main.cpp)

```
#include <QWebView>
#include <QPushButton>

QWebView *web = new QWebView(mainwindow);
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(mainwindow);

web->load(QUrl("http://www.yahoo.com"));
button->setText("Google");

QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), web, SLOT(resetUrl()));
```

Thats about all I got, any help is appreciated. What it says when I try to run this is "'class google' has no member named 'load'".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt C++ Custom Slot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394950/qt-c-custom-slot)

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your class has no load function, you want `web->load(url)` NOT `this->load(url)`