# Qt C++ Custom Slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, slot, qpushbutton

I'm having trouble with making custom slots in Qt. Code:

class.h file:

```
public slots:
    void resetUrl(){
        this->load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
}
```

main.cpp file:

```
#include <QWebView>
#include <QPushButton>

QWebView *web = new QWebView(mainwindow);
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(mainwindow);

web->load(QUrl("http://www.yahoo.com"));
button->setText("Google");

QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), web, SLOT(resetUrl()));
```

It gives me a message saying load is not a recognized member. What do I need to change?

Edit:
Heres the full webview.h file:

```
#ifndef WEBVIEW_H
#define WEBVIEW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebView>


namespace Ui {
class webview;
}

class webview : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit webview(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~webview();

public slots:
    void resetUrl(){
        this->load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
    }

private:
    Ui::webview *ui;
};

#endif // WEBVIEW_H
```

Comment: That doesn't look right. What class is your slot defined in?

Comment: if this is all your code then your cpp file is missing method definitions and if thats your entire .h file you dont have a class at all

Comment: Thats not my entire code, I can paste the rest if you need it

Comment: Can you post the exact error message please&

Comment: Exact error message: 'class webview' has no member named 'load'

Comment: It doesn't have a member named `load`. Look at that class. Do you see a definition for `load` anywhere? Furthermore, [`QMainWindow` has no `load` member either](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qmainwindow-members.html). Perhaps you're trying to use a `QWebView`? It has a `load` member, at least. But you're not using a `QWebView` anywhere (despite including its header).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call a `load()` method of your `webview` class here:

```
void resetUrl(){
    this->load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
}
```

However, your class is derived from `QMainWindow`:

```
class webview : public QMainWindow
```

Both the base class, and your derived class indeed do not have any `load()` method. You should derive your `webview` class from `QWebView` instead of `QMainWindow`. In this case, the base class' `load()` method will be called, and it will work fine.

Comment: When I changed QMainWindow to QWebView in that spot, I got a couple new errors: 'QMainWindow' is not a direct base of 'webview' and no matching function for call to 'Ui::webview::setupUi(webview* const)

Comment: @COnnorM, you also need to change the constructor (to call the constructor of a proper base class). Also get rid of the `ui`, you will not need it (and I'm not even sure the `QWebView` has it).